# jquery ajax call "metho" instead of "method"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, methods

I have a script.js that uses jQuery's ajax function to query string to a php file, it works as expected BUT i find it odd that i must use the "metho" sintax instead of the "method", look at this,

this works

**script.js**

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'php/printers.php',
    metho: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: c,
        orderby: d,
        },
    success: function(output) {

        $('.results').html(output);

        var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('results');
        var rows = tbody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');     

        ajax.applyClass(rows);  
    }
});
```

this doesn't

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'php/printers.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: c,
        orderby: d,
        },
    success: function(output) {

        $('.results').html(output);

        var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('results');
        var rows = tbody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');     

        ajax.applyClass(rows);  
    }
});
```

i'm preplexed that i must use the "metho" instead "method" :O i don't even know how that happened, though it was a typo??

Comment: Can demonstrate at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: There is no option `metho`. An explanation may be that it's working because method is `GET` by default, and it works using `GET`, but it doesn't work using `POST`. Seeing `printers.php` would verify this.

Comment: @Popnoodles _"but it doesn't work when you use POST"_ ? Can describe details ?

Comment: @Popnoodles: Now that you know that's correct, why not post it as an answer? I've deleted the CW (since I still could).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you didn't have to delete it. Even *if it wasn't CW*, it's still fair. You were being nice too... Hats off to you.

Comment: thank you guys for solving the mystery this fast! Would like to add that, method: 'POST' doesn't work at all, i can see in the console that no query string is being created, ajax is sending only php/printers.php instead of php/printers.php?say=Hello&to=World

Comment: @brunobliss: That's because of the way POST and GET work: GET passes all of the parameters in the query string. POST passes it in the body of the request, not the query string.

Comment: @brunobliss Can include `'php/printers.php'` at Question ? Does `'php/printers.php'` expect `GET` request ?

Comment: @Popnoodles _"I don't believe this question is valid for SO"_ ? Reason ?

Comment: Unless it's duplicated somehow, I think it's good question for SO. Assuming its knowledge-base primary purpose, it's totally valid including such information as "`GET` method is default in AJAX request".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *difference* is that the default method of [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is `"GET"`. Since there's no `metho` option for `ajax`, that's ignored and the default is being used. When you specify `method: "POST"`, you're overriding the default, using POST instead of GET.

So we can infer that the script being called works correctly when GET is used, and not when POST is used (probably because of where it looks for the data it receives).